# Safely convert string to date in PySpark

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

This is my code for converting string to date.

```
calendar = (
    myCalendar.withColumn("PeriodFrom", F.to_date("PeriodFrom", "yyyyMMdd"))
)
```

The example values look like this:

```
PeriodFrom
0
19980101
19980201
19980301
```

The zero breaks the code because it is int.

```
AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'gettimestamp(`PeriodFrom`, 'yyyyMMdd')' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires (string or date or timestamp) type, however, '`PeriodFrom`' is of int type.;
```

How can I safely convert string to date without breaking the code? Like ignoring those with wrong format.